# Mean and standard error based on class type using R

Tags: r

I have two raster images (.tif), A and B. A has a range of values, and B is a land cover class (in my case, nine classes). I want to calculate the mean and standard deviation of raster A based on the land cover class of B. I did that using the code below, but class 2 and class 7 have NA values, while there should be some values associated. Why is not calculating the mean and SE of class two? Any solutions? The raster data is too large to upload. Any solutions are appreciated

```
library(raster)
library(dplyr)
luse_3001 <- raster("J:/Chapter 2/TEST_mean/lan_cov_30m_01.tif") #land use
svm_3001 <- raster("J:/Chapter 2/Carbon_hect/svm_30m_01.tif") #range of values
ras_3001<-brick(luse_3001,svm_3001)
df_ras_3001<-data.frame(rasterToPoints(ras_3001))
result_tapply_3001 <- tapply(df_ras_3001$svm_30m_01, df_ras_3001$lan_cov_30m_01, function(x) c(Mean = mean(x), SE = sd(x) / sqrt(length(x))))

df_ras_3001<-data.frame(df_ras_3001[3:4])
result_agg_3001 <- aggregate(. ~ lan_cov_30m_01, data = df_ras_3001, FUN = function(x) c(Mean = mean(x), SE = sd(x) / sqrt(length(x))))

result_dplyr_3001 <- df_ras_3001 %>%
  group_by(lan_cov_30m_01) %>%
  summarize(
    Mean_svm_3001 = mean(svm_30m_01),
    SE_svm_3001 = sd(svm_30m_01) / sqrt(n())
  )
result_dplyr_3001

 lan_cov_30m_01 Mean_svm_3001 SE_svm_3001
           <dbl>         <dbl>       <dbl>
1              1          37.8      0.0122
2              2          NA       NA     
3              3         117.       0.0149
4              4         129.       0.0420
5              5          63.8      0.0233
6              6         121.       0.0510
7              7          NA       NA     
8              8          81.3      0.207 
9              9          94.6      0.0445
```

Comment: No Worries, I got it solved. It was easy just needed to filter using na.rm=T. Thanks

Comment: Nice. Also you can use the `terra` package instead of the `raster`. The former it's the successor of the latter.

Comment: It is acceptable to answer you own questions in the answer box below, so if anyone else gets the same problem then they can see its been answered. It helps if the question title described the problem though, like it should mention NA values or something here.